# Does Hazelcast holds locks indefinitely in jmx?

Tags: hazelcast, locks, jmx-exporter

Recently, I realized that, monitoring hazelcast with jmx, I watch a big number of locks that hazelcast held at that time and correctly unlocks. I can confirm that behaviour inspecting the logs. Is it normal that hazelcast keeps the information of the locks in jmx even when they were correctly unlock? Or It could be an issue instead?

[image: SNAP]

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer from another site and they answered me that the only thing I can do in order to avoid seeing the locks (and eliminate them) is to call explicitly destroy method in each one of those who are still open.

I believe that it is an important issue because having those locks in memory will be provoke OutOfMemoryException eventually.